# Nextjs using rsuitejs and css modules no css in build directory

Tags: reactjs, less, next.js, css-modules, rsuite

I use ***nextjs*** with ***rsuitejs***.

in dev everything works fine.
after build the library css are not in the build directory, 
so ugly page with no css.

i use css module with custom ***webpack*** config.
you can find the project here :

https://github.com/Temkit/rsuitejs-nextjs-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i imported rsuitejs in the less file and it worked,

```
+ @import '~rsuite/styles/less/index';

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #424242cf !important;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
```

the repository is correct now, if someone is facing the same problem check this example https://github.com/Temkit/rsuitejs-nextjs-example

thank you to [simonguo](https://github.com/simonguo)